# How to erase or reload strokes to an InkPicture in VBA for Ms Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to display strokes that I have saved previously on an inkPicture Object in Ms Access (it is on a form via ActiveX).

The strokes are saved in a table as an ole-object in the field 'Strokes'.

Now, doing it once is easy enough (one line of code), I can use this snippet without any problem :

```
Public Sub loadInkImage(MyInkPic As MSINKAUTLib.InkPicture)       

    MyInkPic.Object.Ink.Load (Me.Strokes)       

End Sub
```

The problem comes in when I want to do it a second time : the inkpicture is not 'clean' any more and cannot load the strokes.
Just deleting the existing strokes doesn't work, so how can I fill the same inkpicture again ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to load two sets of strokes into the same object, or just reload a new set of strokes into the InkPicture?  If you want to reload strokes you need to create a new InkDisp Object then assign it to the InkPicture.

```
Public Sub loadInkImage(MyInkPic As MSINKAUTLib.InkPicture)

    Dim newInk As New MSINKAUTLib.InkDisp 'need new object to load new ink

    newInk.Load Me.Strokes 'load in the ink

    Set MyInkPic.Ink = newInk 'set the InkPictures Ink to the new Ink
End Sub
```

Note:  I currently do not have the ability to test this, so it might need tweaking.

Comment: It needed some tweaking :   inkPic.InkEnabled = False and back to true, but other than that : thanks man! wish I could assign more than one point!