# Load an image to an InkPicture control

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im trying to load an image to a inkpicture control in ms access so that I can draw/annotate on top of it.

here is my code

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim b() As Byte
Set v = Me.InkPicture0
b = Nz(Me.Text1.Value, "")
v.Ink.Load b
Me.InkPicture0.Requery
Set v = Nothing
```

this generates an error on line "v.ink.load b", the error is RTE, "you entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property |."

The format appears correct, and what is strange, in some instances it will work once, but not if the same code is run again.

Unfortunately, Microsoft appears to have no documentation on this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider this advice and alternative http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t2022960.html

Comment: Hi Brax, unfortunately nothing there to help. the alternative referred to in that thread is a addin thats nearly 20 years old, it doesnt work with anything that has been released in the past 10 years. I have a bad feeling that microsoft have updated inkpicture over the years and broken it, and so little people use it, they havent realised.

Comment: Brax didn't make that comment. Sorry links didn't help. I run Access 2010. I was able to download and convert Steven Lebans db. It allows drawing with mouse but not load an image and draw over it. Sorry links did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error is caused by using variant type, what leads`v`to get a`CustomControl`that doesn't know about the`Ink`property. Just check that with a [watch](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/debugging/watch-window.htm) on`v`.
If you declare v as`MSINKAUTLib.InkDisp`instead of`Variant`or`Set v = Me.InkPicture0.Object`that error will disapear (but be replaced by`invalid procedure call/argument`).

You can't load sth. to an`InkPicture`controls`Ink`property. You have to load to a new`InkDisp`object and then set the controls`Ink`property to that.

See [How to erase or reload strokes to an InkPicture in VBA for Ms Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3963059/9439330), but avoid the [self assigned declaration](https://rubberduckvba.com/Features/FeatureItem/SelfAssignedDeclaration) used there.

Also you need to disable the controls`Ink`property to set it to the new`Ink`object, with`InkEnabled = False`
See [IInkPicture::get_Ink method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msinkaut/nf-msinkaut-iinkpicture-get_ink#remarks)

To load an image to draw on, use the controls`Picture`property and load a picture with [Application.LoadPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.loadpicture)

```vb
Dim b() As Byte
b = Nz(Me.Text1.Value, "") 'Me.Text1.Value contains saved stroke data
Dim newInk As MSINKAUTLib.InkDisp
Set newInk = New MSINKAUTLib.InkDisp 'need new object to load new ink
newInk.Load b 'load in the ink
Me.InkPicture0.InkEnabled = False
Set Me.InkPicture0.Ink = newInk 'set the InkPictures Ink to the new Ink
Me.InkPicture0.InkEnabled = True
Set newInk = Nothing

Me.InkPicture0.Picture = LoadPicture("path/to/image") 'Load Image from path
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, however, I get an error, on this line:
newInk.Load b 'load in the ink

Error is "method "load" of object "IInkdisp" failed

Could it be that the binary data needs to be in a particular size/format?

Comment: Seems like you need strokes data to load. Maybe you can use`CreateStrokes`method of`InkDisp`or use the`Picture`property of`InkPicture`.

Comment: @DreamsinCode Just use`InkPicture0.Picture = Application.LoadPicture(path/to/pic).

Comment: That did it , thanks a million ComputerVersteher. I really owe you one. 

How did you figure that out? I literally googled for days, emailed Microsoft, etc no one had any idea!

Comment: @DreamsinCode I figured that out by using VBA Object Browser (reveals class members) and reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msinkaut/). Combined with some basic OOP (object-oriented-programming) knowledge, mostly gained from [RubberduckVBA blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/)